# How to send stdout in a tcp packet ? (only using bash commands)

Tags: bash, tcp

I'm doing a project only based on Bash, and I would like to know if there is a way to send the output of a bash command (let's say "ls") into the network (so in a TCP packet)

For instance, I want the output of "ls":

```
ls | some_command_with_a_remote_IP_adresse
```

And I would receive the output of "ls" in a remote computer. I really don't see how to do this, any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bash builtin tcp socket:

```
ls >/dev/tcp/<host>/<port>
```

Comment: @IportSircer Thanks, but how do I receive the info the other side ? Is there a simplier way than wireshark ?

Comment: Yes. Using netcat ( `nc` ) is a more easy way. But it's an old story: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/dev-tcp-listen-instead-of-nc-listen

Comment: @IportSircer Actually I did not find /dev/tcp in my Kali machine...

Comment: @george then use a windows machine